# Formal language vs Active conversation

Tags: discussion

Pardon my choice of words in the title (English is not my first language), but here's what I am trying to ask:
What do we consider a better practice-

Set 1

- Getting to the questions directly, without "hi", "hello", "Good morning"
- Ending the questions with a "question mark" rather than by "Thanks for your time", "Appreciate the help"
- Attempting to make a conversation by adding something like "English is not my first language" in the sentence
- Above answering the question, if something strays from best practices, adding that to the answer

Set 2

- Getting straight to the question or answer, without judging the methods of implementation used by the person who's asking
- Instead of trying to improve an existing answer, posting a new one that deviates from the existing one just by a couple of sentences (This seems to just add to the amount of data on the page without adding as much value)
- Editing out "hi", "thanks", "good luck" from questions and answers

Answer (score 6):

You find a good meta-post (for the full network) here:

[What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

In my eyes, the best part of that post is the following blog-post written by Job Skeet. It is a bit lengthy but is very "to the point":

[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Here we find paragraphs like

> There’s no need to include greetings and sign-offs such as “Hi everyone!” and “Thanks – hope to get an answer soon” in the question. These will often be edited out by other users, as they’re basically a distraction. Greetings at the start of a question are particularly useless as they can take up valuable space in the snippet displayed in the question list.

-

> Don’t add your own answer unless it really is an answer. Often users add extra details in an “answer” when they should really have just edited their question. Likewise editing your question is generally a better idea than adding a long comment to an existing answer – particularly if that comment contains a block of code (which won’t work well in a comment). If you do change the question in response to an answer though, it’s worth adding a comment to the answer just to let the user know that you’ve updated it though… you may well find they quickly edit their answer to match the revised question.

-

> Above all, be polite. Remember that no-one is getting paid to answer your question. Users are giving up their time to help you – so please be appreciative of that. If you’re asking a homework question, explain why you’re asking for help with something that traditionally you’d have to answer all by yourself. If a user suggests that your general approach is wrong and that there’s a better way of doing things, don’t take it personally: they’re trying to help you improve your code. By all means disagree robustly, but don’t start into ad hominem arguments. (This advice applies to answerers as well, of course.)

And here is another blog-post from Jon, helping to write good answers

[Answering technical questions helpfully](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, I think Set 2 and here's why: One of the primary reasons for moderators to keep things organized is because we use this site and it's questions not only for users to ask for help on a certain topic, but it doubles as a search engine result for any question answered. Any conversational verbiage that is used doesn't directly contribute to the answer/question at hand. Having a conversation won't help any other person that finds the thread. It keeps the noise level down, it's easier to read, and it's to the point. Any sort of thank you or polite chatter can be expressed in the comments.

However, if someone has posted an answer that may be slightly different than yours, I would comment on it to give some insight. It may be too redundant to post a new answer if the difference between the two posts are small, or the answer is technically the same.